# How to add a lambda authorizer to AWS SAM application using the same API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I'm trying to add a Lambda Authorizer for a route in my SAM application.

While I can do this easily through AWS console ( API Gateway -> Routes -> Configure Authorization ), when I try to implement authorization via template.yaml file, a seperate API Gateway is created. Thus, I have two different API Gateways ( invoke urls ) for "protected" and public endpoints.

How can I keep both protected and public routes in the same API Gateway?

```
# Settings for a public endpoint:

checkFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: src/handlers/check.handler
    Runtime: nodejs14.x
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 100
    Description: Check function
    Events:
      HttpApiEvent:
        Type: HttpApi
        Properties:
          Path: /check
          Method: POST 

# Settings for a protected endpoint:

protectedFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: src/handlers/protected.handler
    Runtime: nodejs14.x
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 100
    Description: Protected function
    Events:
      HttpApiEvent:
        Type: HttpApi
        Properties:
          ApiId: !Ref protectedApi
          Path: /protected
          Method: GET

protectedApi:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
  Properties:
    StageName: Prod
    Auth:
      DefaultAuthorizer: bh_authorizer
      Authorizers:
        bh_authorizer:
          FunctionArn: !GetAtt authorizerFunction.Arn
          FunctionInvokeRole: !GetAtt authorizerFunctionRole.Arn
          Identity:
            Headers:
              - Authorization
          AuthorizerPayloadFormatVersion: 2.0
          EnableSimpleResponses: true




authorizerFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    Handler: src/handlers/authorizer.handler
    Runtime: nodejs14.x
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    MemorySize: 128
    Timeout: 100
    Description: Authorizer function
```

Comment: Hey, I have a working example with TypeScript here https://github.com/Willis0826/sam-local-authorizer-example

Answer (score 3):

Under the event you wish to keep unprotected, add a separate Auth property:

```
Auth:
  Authorizer: NONE
```

So in your case, the event for the `checkFunction` resource would look like this:

```yaml
  Events:
    HttpApiEvent:
      Type: HttpApi
      Properties:
        Path: /check
        Method: POST
        ApiId: !Ref protectedApi  # ADD THIS TO MAKE SURE IT'S PART OF THE SAME API
        Auth:
          Authorizer: NONE
```